# Generic version vs interface version of a method

Tags: c#, generics, interface

What is the difference between these two methods?

**first:**

```
public static int Foo<T>(T first, T second) where T:IComparable
{
    return first.CompareTo(second)
}
```

**second:**

```
public static int Foo(IComparable first, IComparable second)
{
    return first.CompareTo(second);
}
```

Comment: it is not exact duplicate of that post, because here we have two parameter and it change some criteria. look at the first answer to see the difference

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the first method, the types of the two parameters have to be same, e.g., `int` and `int`. The type has to implement the `IComparable` interface.

For the second method, the two parameters can have different types. Both types must implement the `IComparable` interface, but do not have to be the same, e.g., `int` and `string`.

Note that the [IComparable.CompareTo method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx) will likely throw an exception if the types are not the same. So it's better to make sure that the types *are* actually the same. You can do this by using your first method, or even better by using the generic [IComparable<T> interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx).

---

The follow-up question is, of course: What is the difference between these two methods?

**first:**

```
public static int Foo<T1, T2>(T1 first, T2 second) where T1 : IComparable<T2>
{
    return first.CompareTo(second);
}
```

**second:**

```
public static int Foo<T>(IComparable<T> first, T second)
{
    return first.CompareTo(second)
}
```

Answer: The first method doesn't box the first argument, while the second method does.

Answer (score 1):

From the code fragment provided the difference that can say, that

Generics version:

- for generics new code will be generated for every type defined

`Foo<Class1>`, `Foo<Class2>`, `Foo<Class3>`.

- you need to define a type at *compile time*

Interface version:

- benefit from OOP concepts, hiding implementation details from the actual code.
- runtime type definiton (more flexibility), but less "generic" in terms of pure sence of that word.

In general: *interface version* is more flexible but less generic (everything, by the way,  depends naturally on concrete code implementaiton).